# function to get cursor position seems to error with its positioning for input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to validate input in input boxes, so i was going to need to find a way to delete a character added to a string.   My thought, use the cursor location.  My implementation should work but you can see the glitches for the few few characters each time an input gets focus.

my fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/TSwyk/

What am i doing wrong?   When i want to validate, i dont want it to check, and delete the wrong character.

My javascript code is (using jquery 1.7.2 i believe):

```
function getCursorPosition(jqueryItem)
{
    var input = jqueryItem.get(0);
    if (!input) return; // No (input) element found
    if ('selectionStart' in input) {
        // Standard-compliant browsers
        return input.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        // IE
        input.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        var selLen = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
        sel.moveStart('character', -input.value.length);
        $("#sel").html(sel);
        $("#selLen").html(selLen);
        return sel.text.length - selLen;
     }
}
    $(function(){
        alert("loaded");
        $("input").on("input", function(){
            var cPos = getCursorPosition($(this));
            $("#cursorPos").html(cPos);
            var FLAG = 'a';
            $("#charatpos").html($(this).val().charAt(cPos));
            $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"count").html($(this).val().length);
            if($(this).val().charAt(cPos) == FLAG){
                var str = $(this).val();
                var sArr = str.split("");
                sArr.splice(cPos,1);
                str = sArr.join("");
                $(this).val(str);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by changing the event to be **.keypress()** instead of **on("input")**.  There will not be discrepancies that way and still get the job done.  As a sidenote, make sure when you use keypress(), for the deletion section you add a simple:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

so that way propigation doesnt continue.  That way, the new key will not actually be pressed and show up at all as well.